# Libc.so crash in firebase log

Tags: unity-game-engine

After I upgrade firebase crashlytics to18.2.4 ,this crash happened.
but I also modify other c# codes  like I usually do.
This crash happen every 50 people,i can not suffer it but have no methods.
Who knows what may cause this carsh?

Below is the log in firebase.

```
Crashed：Thread #1
SIGBUS 0x00000000a33df080
0
libmonochrome.so (lack)
1
libmonochrome.so (lack)
2
libmonochrome.so (lack)
3
libmonochrome.so (lack)
4
libmonochrome.so (lack)
5
libmonochrome.so (lack)
6
libmonochrome.so (lack)
7
libmonochrome.so (lack)
```